# codeigniter join problem

Tags: database, codeigniter, join

i have 2 tabels in my database "forum_traad" and "forum_kommentare" but they have the same row "indhold" so when i try to join forum_traad and forum_kommentare and i wanna echo the "indhold" row from "forum_traad" it echo the "indhold" from "forum_kommentare", what can i do?

my view:

```
<div id="forum">


  <?php 
  if($query)
  {
  ?>
  <div class="forum_headline">Forum kategori - Forum tråde - <?php echo $query->overskrift; ?></div><!-- forum_headline -->
  <div class="forum_profil_img"></div><!-- forum_profil_img -->
  <div class="forum_post_content">
   <span style="font-size:15px;"><?php echo anchor('profil/'.$query->brugernavn, $query->brugernavn); ?></span>
   <span style="font-size:11px; margin-left:3px; color:#686868;"><i> Siger</i></span><br>
   <?php echo $query->indhold; 
   echo "<br>ID: ".$query->id;
   ?>
  </div><!-- forum_post_content -->


  <?php
  } else {
   echo "Der blev ikke fundet nogen post";
  }
  ?>

</div><!-- forum -->
```

My model

```
    function posts($id)
 {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('forum_traad');
  $this->db->join('forum_kommentare', 'forum_kommentare.fk_forum_traad', 'forum_traad.id');
  $this->db->where('forum_traad.id', $id);

  $query = $this->db->get();

  if($query->num_rows > 0)
  {
   return $query->row();
  } else {
   return false;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give them a different name:

```
$this->db->select('forum_traad.indhold as traad_indhold,
                   forum_kommentare.indhold as kommentare_indhold');
```

If you need the functionality of * you can in addition select:

```
$this->db->select('forum_traad.indhold as traad_indhold,
                   forum_kommentare.indhold as kommentare_indhold,
                   forum_traad.*,
                   forum_kommentare.*');
```

Comment: when i try the last i got this error

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM (`forum_traad`) JOIN `forum_kommentare` ON `forum_kommentare`.`fk_forum_t' at line 1

SELECT `forum_traad`.`indhold` as traad_indhold, `forum_kommentare`.`indhold` as kommentare_indhold, * FROM (`forum_traad`) JOIN `forum_kommentare` ON `forum_kommentare`.`fk_forum_traad` WHERE `forum_traad`.`id` = '13'

Comment: Oh, sorry... you cannot use the plain * when you are mixing it with single fields and you've got multiple tables. Corrected the example.